# Java RMI Server Registry-Lookup Message exchange

Tags: java, tcp, wireshark, rmi

ive built a simple Client-Server-application that also includes an auditlogserver that is implemented via JavaRMI.

In the screenshot [image: Wireshark-Screenshot] attached you can see a Wireshark sequence that shows the message exchange while the Chat-Server connects to the RMI-Registry in order to get the remote object reference. My question is: Shortly after the 3-Way-Handshake you can see a Method call "JRMI, Call" - What method call can this be? Does it have to be the call of a remote method?

Because the Chatserver connects to the RMI-Registry via Naming.lookup but I doesn't directly initiates an remote method call... Maybe somebody can help me figuring out what this method call during the Registry lookup is about - Thanks in advance!

I ran the ChatServer that connects to the Registry. I thought it would only get the reference to the remote object but it initiates an method call that I don't understand

Comment: That's the actual `Registry.lookup()` call, which is itself a remote method invocation.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your help! That is also what I thought, but the Naming.lookup() call in the chat server (192.168.0.20) does initiate the connection to the registry in the first place - how can this method call then again initiate a JRMI Call?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. You need a connection to execute an RMI call over.